# JavaServer Faces keyboard layout changes

Tags: jsf

I got a few Input components on page and while I set focus on one of them by mouse keyboard layout doesn't change, but if I do it by TAB-batton on keybord then keyboard layout changes on US. Using GlassFish server by the way. Why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Strange.. Does this happen in other forms ?

Comment: No, other forms on other pages is fine. On the page with problem I use a commandLinks referenced on methods of bean such like this:
public String russianAction(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return null;
    }

Comment: Prefer using these action methods with usual commandButton rather than commandLink.

Comment: Sorry, mistake was on inputSecret component, it changes keyboard layout. But why and how make it to not to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the OS X feature to input text in <input type="password" /> only in English